# How to set up Hyper-V virtual NIC to have an IP address in same subnet of the Physical NIC?

Tags: networking, router, ip, hyper-v, network-adapter

Is it possible to have on a virtual NIC an IP address in the same subnet of the Physical NIC?
But I want to differenciate the IPs.
For example:
My physical network card have the following IP: 192.168.0.20/24
I'd like to have the following IP on my virtual card: 192.168.0.30/24

When I log in on my router page I see only the virtual card IP. How is it possible? How can I see the two IPs?

Comment: To do so, create an External adapter in Hyper-V's Virtual Switch Manager, assigning it to whatever physical network adapter is connected to the router

Comment: It can be a solution. Maybe I have already tried it. But I cannot see my physical network IP. Oddly I only see, on my router, the virtual network card IP. I want to see both.

Comment: What your router is showing has nothing to do with Hyper-V. If you're connected to your router with the same physical network adapter, your router should show both as connected, however that's an issue with the router, not Hyper-V. Open a terminal on the host and issue `arp -a | findstr 192.168.0.*`, then match that info to your router